# Compare two Javascript Arrays and remove Duplicates

Tags: javascript

It is working well is there any other better way to remove duplicates from one array if it has elements of another array ?.

```
<script>
var array1 = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f");
var array2 = new Array("c","e");

for (var i = 0; i<array2.length; i++) {
    var arrlen = array1.length;
    for (var j = 0; j<arrlen; j++) {
        if (array2[i] == array1[j]) {
            array1 = array1.slice(0, j).concat(array1.slice(j+1, arrlen));
        }
    }
}
alert(array1);

</script>
```

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think this would be perform-ant.  You're doing 2 loops

Answer (score 225, accepted):

```
array1 = array1.filter(function(val) {
  return array2.indexOf(val) == -1;
});
```

Or, with the availability of ES6:

```
array1 = array1.filter(val => !array2.includes(val));
```

[filter() reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[indexOf() reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

[includes() reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Comment: As a side note and explanation of the above code : "indexOf : Returns the first (least) index of an element within the array equal to the specified value, or -1 if none is found." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray)

Comment: I like it, but it definitely needs explanation, or at least a link guiding someone to the right place that explains it.

Comment: Great piece of code, though be aware that it doesn't work if you have nested arrays.

Comment: Works beautiful for lists of unique values, but what about lists with duplicates in them, such as comparing a "ransom note" with a list of words in a magazine (assuming case must match and must have the right number of each word)...

Comment: It worked for me . (array1 = array1.filter(val => !array2.includes(val));). 
Thank you. :)

Comment: Although a nice solution but if user wants to support IE then includes does not support.

Answer (score 10):

The trick, for reasons that are beyond me, is to loop the outer loop downwards (i--) and the inner loop upwards (j++).

See the example bellow:

```
function test() {
  var array1 = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f");
  var array2 = new Array("c","e");
  for (var i = array1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
      if (array1[i] === array2[j]) {
        array1.splice(i, 1);
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(array1)
  }
```

How do I know this? See the below:

```
for( var i =myArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
  for( var j=0; j<toRemove.length; j++){
    if(myArray[i] === toRemove[j]){
      myArray.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

or

```
var myArray = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'chirag', place: 'bangalore'}, 
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}, 
  {name: 'chandan', place: 'mumbai'}
];
var toRemove = [
  {name: 'deepak', place: 'bangalore'},
  {name: 'alok', place: 'berhampur'}
];

for( var i=myArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
    for( var j=0; j<toRemove.length; j++){
        if(myArray[i] && (myArray[i].name === toRemove[j].name)){
            myArray.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}

alert(JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

On that note, would anyone be able to explain why the outer loop needs to be looped downwards (--)?

Good luck!

Comment: How can remove the duplicate without using property name.like without specify any array obj name .

Comment: @vishal change array1[i] === array2[j] to extend the propery name of the item. That makes it now `array1[i].propertyOfThisItem === array2[j].possiblyTheSameProperty`

Answer (score 7):

**You can try this**

```
array1 = array1 .filter(val => {
             return !array2.find((val2)=>{
              //  console.log({valueID:val.id+":"+val2.id});
                return val.id===val2.id
             }) 
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the Set.prototype Constructor: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

```
let array1 = Array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
let array2 = Array('c', 'e', 'g')
let concat = array1.concat(array2) // join arrays => [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'c', 'e', 'g' ]

// Set will filter out duplicates automatically
let set = new Set(concat) // => Set { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' }

// Use spread operator to extend Set to an Array
let result = [...set]
console.log(result) // =>  [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g' ]
```

Comment: @Drenai yes it works for objects if you stringify :)

Answer (score 2):

use `Array.splice()`

```
var array1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
var array2 = ['4', '5'];
var index;
for (var i=0; i<array2.length; i++) {
    index = array1.indexOf(array2[i]);
    if (index > -1) {
        array1.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution to remove duplicate in ES6.

```
let foundDuplicate = false;
existingOptions.some(existingItem => {
  result = result.filter(item => {
    if (existingItem.value !== item.value) {
      return item;
    } else {
      foundDuplicate = true;
    }
  });
  return foundDuplicate;
});
```

I used this approach because in my case I was having array of objects and indexOf was having problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

This my solution

`array1 = array1.filter(function(val) {
  return array2.indexOf(val.toString()) == -1;
});`

Comment: Was the top answer not sufficient? Why is the additional `.toString()` necessary?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function () {
        var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm'];
        var array2 = ['c', 'h', 'k'];
        var array3 = [];
        var SecondarrayIndexcount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
                if (array1[i] !== array2[j]) {
                    if (SecondarrayIndexcount === (array2.length - 1)) {
                        array3.push(array1[i]);
                        SecondarrayIndexcount = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    SecondarrayIndexcount++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (var i in array3) {
            alert(array3[i]);
        }
    }
</script>
```