# Array subtraction for duplicate entries

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet of code which I am using for getting difference between two arrays. The problem is that it doesn't work for duplicate entries and deletes the entry only once, thus leaving a copy of it behind. Can someone tell me the fix to this?

```
function arr_diff(a1, a2){
    var a=[], diff=[];
    for(var i=0;i<a1.length;i++)
        a[a1[i]]=true;
    for(var i=0;i<a2.length;i++)
        if(a[a2[i]]) delete a[a2[i]];
        else a[a2[i]]=true;
    for(var k in a)
        diff.push(+k);
    return diff;
}
```

Comment: You should use brackets `{` and `}` when nesting multiple statements. Have you tried that?

Comment: You may also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates

Comment: can you provide an Input where it fails.

Comment: @Mritunjay `arr_diff([1,2,3], [1,3,3])` returns `[2, 3]`

Comment: @DavidSherret and expected should be also.

Comment: @Mritunjay expected should be `[2]` since `1` and `3` appear in both arrays.

Comment: Thanks @DavidSherret, that link helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Give them a state. `1` for only in the first array, `2` for only in the second, `3` for in both. Then only return the ones with the state `1` and `2`:

```
function arr_diff(a1, a2) {
    var a = {}, diff = [], i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        a[a1[i]] = 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < a2.length; i++) {
        if (typeof a[a2[i]] === "undefined") {
            a[a2[i]] = 2;
        }
        else if (a[a2[i]] === 1) {
            a[a2[i]] = 3;
        }
    }

    for (k in a) {
        if (a[k] !== 3) {
            diff.push(+k);
        }
    }

    return diff;
}
```