# compare two arrays and return duplicate values

Tags: javascript, arrays, meteor, underscore.js

How may I retrieve an element that exists in two different arrays of the same document.

For example. In Posts collection, document has the fields 'interestbycreator' and 'interestbyreader.' Each field contain user Ids.

```
'interestbycreator':  //an array of ids here. IdA, idB, IdC, IdD, IdE,
'interestbyreader':  //an array of ids here. IdB, idE, iDF
```

Basically I wish to find all the ids that exist in both arrays, so that should be IdB and IdE.

I am able to pluck all the values from an array with underscore and store them in a variable. Can they be compared to each other this way and return duplicates? Or can someone shed some light on another solution.

Example to retrieve all Ids from 'interestbyreader

```
var interestbypostcreater = Posts.find({_id: Meteor.user().profile.postcreated[0]}, {fields: {interestbyreader: 1}}).fetch();
var interestedReaderIds = _.chain(interestbypostcreator).pluck('interestbyreader').flatten().value();
```

Assume I have the other array 'interestbycreator' stored in a variable called interestIdcreator, can they be compared to find duplicates and return these duplicates?

Comment: Have you considered using `_.intersection` ? http://underscorejs.org/#intersection

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As Saimeunt pointed out, it can be done as

```
var x = ['IdA', 'idB', 'IdC', 'IdD', 'IdE'];
var y = ['idB', 'IdE', 'IdF'];

var z = _.intersection(x, y);
```

Answer (score 19):

As [saimeunt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2530970/saimeunt) said in the comments when you have access to underscore use [intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) but you can also do it with plain javascript:

```js
var x = ['IdA', 'idB', 'IdC', 'IdD', 'IdE'];
var y = ['idB', 'IdE', 'IdF'];

var z = x.filter(function(val) {
  return y.indexOf(val) != -1;
});

console.log(z);
```

The array `z` contains the double entries then.

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930567/441907

Comment: How can I get the 'return' results inside another variable? I want to preserve them as an array and not convert them so I can use the variable to query the database.Thank you for your help

Comment: You have to deep copy the source array e.g. with `slice()` http://jsfiddle.net/94mjfhyh/

Comment: In exchange for memory this can be sped up by using a [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for lookups.