# Find and remove object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have 2 arrays of objects.
Array1:

```
[{ id: 2, ref: 1010101 },
 { id: 2, ref: 1010107 }]
```

Array2:

```
[{ id: 2, ref: 10010001 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010002 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010003 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010006 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010007 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010008 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010009 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10020005 },
 { id: 2, ref: 1010101 }]
```

I need to do 2 tasks:
1. Find what elements of **array1** are in **array2** . After find Items, Im going to do something with that elements.
2. Remove elements found from **array2**. After I do something with my found items, I need to remove each item found.

I was trying to do it with [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) but without success.

I need something like this:

```
if(elementFound) {
  //do something
  doSomething(item);
  //after it, remove from array2
  removeItemFromArray2(item);
}
```

Thanks, I think there is an easy way to do it with lodash.

Comment: Why use lodash when you've got [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) and [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)?

Comment: Array#filter() should do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Javascript Arrays and remove Duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Since two objects with the same key/values aren't the same, you can only use indexOf if you stringify each object first. Depending on the size of the array, comparing strings and then slicing out the index from the original array might outperform using a nested filter which will do multiple loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There certainly is! You can use `_.remove` to programmatically remove elements from `array2` if they meet a certain predicate. In your case, that predicate would be "is the element in `array1`",

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 2, ref: 1010101 },
 { id: 2, ref: 1010107 }]

var array2 = [{ id: 2, ref: 10010001 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010002 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010003 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010006 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010007 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010008 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10010009 },
 { id: 2, ref: 10020005 },
 { id: 2, ref: 1010101 }]

_.remove(array2, function (item) {
  return _.find(array1, item);
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(array2, null, 2) + "</pre>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Array.prototype.filter` at this context to achieve what you want,

```
var filteredArray = Array2.filter(function(itm){
 return Array1.filter(function(itmIn){
   return itmIn.id === itm.id && itmIn.ref === itm.ref;
 }).length == 0;
});
```

Comment: what is `length == 0` for? I dont get it

Answer (score 2):

There is one specific lodash function for this:

```js
var array1 = [
  { id: 2, ref: 1010101 },
  { id: 2, ref: 1010107 }
];

var array2 = [
  { id: 2, ref: 10010001 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10010002 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10010003 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10010006 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10010007 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10010008 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10010009 },
  { id: 2, ref: 10020005 },
  { id: 2, ref: 1010101 }
];

var res = _.differenceBy(array2, array1, 'ref');

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + "</pre>")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I knew this lodash function, but I was looking for a **find** first (do something) and after it, **remove** it. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

A solution with a linear O.

```js
var array1 = [{ id: 2, ref: 1010101 }, { id: 2, ref: 1010107 }],
    array2 = [{ id: 2, ref: 10010001 }, { id: 2, ref: 10010002 }, { id: 2, ref: 10010003 }, { id: 2, ref: 10010006 }, { id: 2, ref: 10010007 }, { id: 2, ref: 10010008 }, { id: 2, ref: 10010009 }, { id: 2, ref: 10020005 }, { id: 2, ref: 1010101 }],
    result = function (a, b) {
        function k(x) { return x.id + '|' + x.ref; }
        var o = {};
        b.forEach(function (c) {
            o[k(c)] = true;
        });
        a.forEach(function (c) {
            o[k(c)] = false;
        });
        return b.filter(function (c) {
            return o[k(c)];
        });
    }(array1, array2);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This solutions it's very unclear for me, but thanks anyway.