# Splice method not removing the correct elements. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am supposed to write a function that passes two arrays, a and b, and removes elements from 'a' that are found in 'b'.

This is my code

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
  for( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for( var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if(a[j] === b[i]) {
        a.splice(j,1);
      }
    }
   }
   return a;
}
```

I passed the values, `array_diff([1,2,1,2,3,1],[1,2]);` and I got  `[2,3]` as the answer. I checked the for loops by using this code:

```
function array_diff(a, b) {
  var unique = [];
  for( var i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    for( var j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
      if(a[j] === b[i]) {
        unique.push(a[j]);
      }
    }
   }
   return unique;
}
```

then I passed the same values, and I got the array `[1,1,1,2,2]`. If my for loops are identifying with the correct values, then why isn't the splice method removing the exact values?

Need your help.

Thank You

Comment: `[1.2]` - was it a float number in your code, or it was a typo?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/14930567/6935229

Comment: @Avi Hi, sorry, the question title is a bit  confusing. I've edited it. I wanted to know why doesn't the splice method remove the correct values?

Comment: @georg can you please reopen the question. I need to know why doesn't the splice method work here. I have edited the question title accordingly.

Comment: @AyushBahuguna splice mutates the array: you're removing elements and therefore mutating its length. This messes up your indexes and therefore you get an invalid result. Just to prove it, use splice.(j,1,5) and you'll see you get an array with only fives and one three

Comment: @acontell hey thank you. I started from the end of the array a, and it worked.