# How to get duplicate records in two object array of JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

My first Json Array is like :

```
[
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"256","mail":"abc@abc.com"},
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"261","mail":"hg1@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"260","mail":"hg2@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"276","mail":"hg3@vrz.net"}
]
```

and second one is:

```
[
    {"Invent":"14","Beze":"259","mail":"abc1@abc.com"},
    {"Invent":"24","Beze":"264","mail":"hg4@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"34","Beze":"260","mail":"hg2@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"44","Beze":"276","mail":"hg7@vrz.net"}
]
```

i want to compare these array to find duplicate rows if 'Beze' value has duplicate entry...

Comment: Seriously? You can't write a loop and comparison? Also, `mail` values need to be strings too.

Comment: So, if you get a duplicate then what would you do?

Comment: Sorry for my earlier comment. Please show your efforts using a [mcve], and try [doing some research beforehand](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates).

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21987909/difference-between-two-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Assumption:

1) you have to fill a third array with duplicate records.

2) There are no duplicates entries within each array

```
var arr1 = [
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"256","mail":"abc@abc.com"},
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"261","mail":"hg1@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"260","mail":"hg2@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"4","Beze":"276","mail":"hg3@vrz.net"}
];

var arr2 = [
    {"Invent":"14","Beze":"259","mail":"abc1@abc.com"},
    {"Invent":"24","Beze":"264","mail":"hg4@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"34","Beze":"260","mail":"hg2@vrz.net"},
    {"Invent":"44","Beze":"276","mail":"hg7@vrz.net"}
];

var arr3 = [];

arr1.forEach(function(arr1Item) {
    arr2.forEach(function(arr2Item) {
        if (arr1Item.Beze === arr2Item.Beze)
            arr3.push(arr1Item);
    })
});

console.log(arr3);
```