# find and merge duplicate match with array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following is an array of product which has been find and process on contact data and creates the possible array of merge occurrences.
In the following arrProduct, I would like to filter duplicate array and merge with existing array and finally create a unique array product called arrFinalProduct.

**Array product**

```
arrProduct = 
    [ 
      [ 0 ],
      [ 1, 2 ],
      [ 2 ],
      [ 3 ],
      [ 4, 5, 6, 10 ],
      [ 5, 6, 7, 11 ],
      [ 6 ],
      [ 7, 11 ],
      [ 8 ],
      [ 9 ],
      [ 10 ],
      [ 11 ],
      [ 12 ],
      [ 13, 14 ],
      [ 14 ]
    ]
```

**Final product**

```
arrFinalProduct = 
    [ 
      [ 0 ],
      [ 1, 2 ],
      [ 3 ],
      [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11 ],
      [ 8 ],
      [ 9 ],
      [ 12 ],
      [ 13, 14 ]
    ]
```

arrProduct is the product array and arrFinalProduct is the final product array. The basic logic is that we require merging array, if any occurrences match found from an array.

Let's say value 0 is not found in any index in arrProduct so it does not merge and push into arrFinalProduct, 
arrProduct value 2  is found on 1st and 2nd index so it may merge with 1st index and become [1,2] and delete 3rd index of [2].
arrProduct index 5 have two common value 5 and 6 and it also in index 6 so it may merge into 1 and become "4,5,6,7" and so on...

This process is going to process data recursively until I found unique value from an array. So it probably merges array horizontally.

Hope reader may get an enough idea.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, actually I did the process on data and find duplicate data occurrences. and this is the array of those occurences.

Comment: _Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it._

Comment: Can you include that code in the question as well?

Comment: @Andreas: As I already told to Nisarg that this is the final array created by me after a process on duplicate contact data the occurences that are actually a product of array. I am not here post a question in the second minute of creating an array. I am not able to find some concrete way to solve an issue. So I do not expect to get a code but get a guideline. Hope you may understand.

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a clear path from input to output - perhaps you need to explain it better ...

Comment: If you don't want code, you've come to the wrong fourm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Javascript Arrays and remove Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates)

Comment: specifically, what is the logic of `[ 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11 ],` in the output

Comment: What is the `duplicate array` here? What is the `existing array` here? What will be `final unique array` would look like? Please be more descriptive about the code you have and what issue you are facing with it.

Comment: @Jaromonda: ready question now probably get an enough idea after reading a question.

Comment: @Palash: ready question now probably get an enough idea after reading a question.

Comment: @IsmailFarooq: it's not a duplicate question kindly ready question briefly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you could search for exisitent items in the result set and join the arrays with same items.

The order of items is the same as the appearance.

```js
var array = [[0], [1, 2], [2], [3], [4, 5, 6, 10], [5, 6, 7, 11], [6], [7, 11], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13, 14], [14]],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r.some(function (b, i, bb) {
            if (a.some(c => b.includes(c))) {
                bb[i] = [...new Set(b.concat(a))];
                return true;
            }
        }) || r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```