# How to compare two objects and remove the duplicate objects by value in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I am having two objects i would like to compare those objects and remove the duplicate objects by value and show the rest of the objects.I have tried lodash omit but it doesn't works.

```
    let users = [
  {value: "6qcuXSLWAnVospWkugWa", label: "Karthi"},
  {value: "Qk8pc08WmcacM7BqFxow", label: "Karthi"},
  {value: "evLkHAkhNZ9qqeYc1tDn", label: "Sankar"},
  {value: "WE6kIW8sGkEuMRXQgQPT", label: "User8"},
  {value: "km2jHXDQgPXdBY4jq6dG", label: "User50"},
  {value: "ObQhbfH3YroudLVz5YkY", label: "User10"}
]

let selectedUsers = [
{value: "6qcuXSLWAnVospWkugWa", label: "Karthi"},
{value: "Qk8pc08WmcacM7BqFxow", label: "Karthi"},
{value: "evLkHAkhNZ9qqeYc1tDn", label: "Sankar"},
{value: "WE6kIW8sGkEuMRXQgQPT", label: "User8"},
{value: "km2jHXDQgPXdBY4jq6dG", label: "User50"},
{value: "ObQhbfH3YroudLVz5YkY", label: "User10"},
{value: "L9FW5oXDlDmzhWxhGEdu", label: "Govind"}
]
```

Without using multiple loops is it possible to remove the duplicates

Comment: Why are `users` and `selectedUsers` objects instead of arrays?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: @David it is an typo it is array only

Comment: @HassanImam expected ouput is [{value: "L9FW5oXDlDmzhWxhGEdu", label: "Govind"}]

Comment: What is the criteria of defining whether objects are duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Javascript Arrays and remove Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine equality for two JavaScript objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201183/how-to-determine-equality-for-two-javascript-objects)

Comment: i still dont get what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

```
var userObjectOfObjects = users.reduce(
        (acc, o) => {
            acc[o.value] = o;
            return acc;
        }, {} )

var selectUsersObject = selectedUsers.reduce(
    (acc, o) => {
        if(userObjectOfObjects[o.value]){
            acc.duplicates.push(o)
            return acc;
        }
        else {
            acc.objectWithoutDuplicates.push(o)
        }
        acc.uniqueList[o.value] = o;
        return acc;
    }, { uniqueList: {}, objectWithoutDuplicates:[], duplicates: [] } )


selectUsersObject.uniqueList = {
    ...selectUsersObject.uniqueList,
    ...userObjectOfObjects
}

var uniqueList = Object.values(selectUsersObject.uniqueList)
var duplicates = selectUsersObject.duplicates
var noRepetition = selectUsersObject.objectWithoutDuplicates
```

Answer (score 0):

`let result = _.unionBy(users, selectedUsers, 'value');`

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher it essentially returns the unique objects by value.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I thought that was self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `differenceWith` and `isEqual` to get the unique value from the `selectedUsers`.

```js
let users = [{value: "6qcuXSLWAnVospWkugWa", label: "Karthi"}, {value: "Qk8pc08WmcacM7BqFxow", label: "Karthi"}, {value: "evLkHAkhNZ9qqeYc1tDn", label: "Sankar"}, {value: "WE6kIW8sGkEuMRXQgQPT", label: "User8"}, {value: "km2jHXDQgPXdBY4jq6dG", label:
"User50"}, {value: "ObQhbfH3YroudLVz5YkY", label: "User10"}],
    selectedUsers = [{value: "6qcuXSLWAnVospWkugWa", label: "Karthi"}, {value: "Qk8pc08WmcacM7BqFxow", label: "Karthi"}, {value: "evLkHAkhNZ9qqeYc1tDn", label: "Sankar"}, {value: "WE6kIW8sGkEuMRXQgQPT",
label: "User8"}, {value: "km2jHXDQgPXdBY4jq6dG", label: "User50"}, {value: "ObQhbfH3YroudLVz5YkY", label: "User10"}, {value: "L9FW5oXDlDmzhWxhGEdu", label: "Govind"}],
    result = _.differenceWith(selectedUsers, users, _.isEqual);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any solution to this would require multiple loops. It's either you write multiple loops or the shorthand code you write uses multiple loops internally.

This one-liner should work for you

```
const arrWithoutDup = selectedUsers.filter(sUser => users.filter(user => sUser.value === user.value && sUser.value === user.value).length === 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming for objects to duplicate, `value` and `label` values should be same.

You can try following using simple Javascript with linear complexity. Firstly, convert `users` array into an object and then using `Array.filter` on second array, filter out the duplicate objects.

```js
let users = [{value: "6qcuXSLWAnVospWkugWa", label: "Karthi"},{value: "Qk8pc08WmcacM7BqFxow", label: "Karthi"},{value: "evLkHAkhNZ9qqeYc1tDn", label: "Sankar"},{value: "WE6kIW8sGkEuMRXQgQPT", label: "User8"},{value: "km2jHXDQgPXdBY4jq6dG", label: "User50"},{value: "ObQhbfH3YroudLVz5YkY", label: "User10"}];
let selectedUsers = [{value: "6qcuXSLWAnVospWkugWa", label: "Karthi"},{value: "Qk8pc08WmcacM7BqFxow", label: "Karthi"},{value: "evLkHAkhNZ9qqeYc1tDn", label: "Sankar"},{value: "WE6kIW8sGkEuMRXQgQPT", label: "User8"},{value: "km2jHXDQgPXdBY4jq6dG", label: "User50"},{value: "ObQhbfH3YroudLVz5YkY", label: "User10"},{value: "L9FW5oXDlDmzhWxhGEdu", label: "Govind"}];

let uersObj = users.reduce((a,c) => Object.assign(a, {[c.value]:c.label}), {});
let result = selectedUsers.filter(v => !uersObj[v.value] || uersObj[v.value] !== v.label);
console.log(result);
```