# Javascript: Remove duplicates in an array by compare function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects like this:

```
const array = [
    {name:'obj1', address: 987, id: '123', location: 'zyx' },
    {name:'obj2', address: 654, id: '456', location: 'wvu'},
    {name:'obj3', address: 321, id: '123', location: 'zyx'}
];
```

and I want to remove the duplicates with a function to compare them:

```
const compareObjects = (a, b) => {
    return a.id === b.id && a.location === b.location;
}
```

The function only compares the relevant properties of the objects.

How can I remove the duplicates from the array with this function?

Edit: To clarify, I want to use a function to compare some properties of the object and not the whole object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare two Javascript Arrays and remove Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates)

Comment: Use a nested loop over the array and remove an element if it exists in the sub-list before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array by checking the object of the temporary result set.

```js
const
    array = [{ name:'obj1', address: 987, id: '123', location: 'zyx' }, { name:'obj2', address: 654, id: '456', location: 'wvu' }, { name:'obj3', address: 321, id: '123', location: 'zyx' }],
    compareObjects = (a, b) => a.id === b.id && a.location === b.location,
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => {
        if (!r.some(compareObjects.bind(null, o))) {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try a function like below

```
 function unique(array , compareObjects){
    array.sort(compareObjects);
    for(var i = 1; i < array.length; ){
        if( compareObjects(array[i-1], array[i]) === 0){
            array.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The obvious solution is to compare each element against each other element (except for itself):

```
 const result = array.filter((el, i) => !arr.some((el2, i2) => i < i2 && compareObjects(el, el2));
```

However that is O(n²) which will get very slow for large datasets, in that case hashtables help you:

```
const dupes = new Set;
const key = el => el.id + "|" + el.location;

const result = array.filter(it => !dupes.has(key(el)) && dupes.add(key(el)));
```

That is O(n) (aka *super fast*, but consumes more memory).