# Checking for duplicate values in a list of objects against another list of objects

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, apex

I've got two lists as following:

```
listOne = [
    {phone: "123", name: "Joey"},
    {phone: "456", name: "Erik"},
    {phone: "789", name: "Teddy"},
]
```

and

```
listTwo = [
    {phone: "123", name: "Joey", accoundId: "ID_001"},
    {phone: "456", name: "Erik", accoundId: "ID_006"},
    {phone: "5553", name: "Sebastian", accoundId: "ID_010"},
]
```

How would I compare these two lists, and for each duplicate (exact matches for `phone` and `name`), if a duplicate exists, put the values in `listThree` with the `accountId` found in `listTwo`

As such:

```
listThree = [
    {phone: "123", name: "Joey", accountId: "ID_001"},
    {phone: "456", name: "Erik", accountId: "ID_006"},
]
```

JavaScript, Python or Apex solutions are highly appreciated

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: For javascript: try using the `filter()` method, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates) stackoverflow post

Comment: The end goal is to use it in Apex (Salesforce proprietary programming language)

Comment: You say this is for use in apex but this is not really how data in Salesforce looks. Is this data coming from an Sobject (like Contact) or some other class structure?

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [
    {"phone": "123", "name": "Joey"},
    {"phone": "456", "name": "Erik"},
    {"phone": "789", "name": "Teddy"},
]

list2 = [
    {"phone": "123", "name": "Joey", "accountid": "ID_001"},
    {"phone": "456", "name": "Erik", "accountid": "ID_006"},
    {"phone": "5553", "name": "Sebastian", "accountid": "ID_010"},
]

list3=[]
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if i['name'] == j['name'] and i['phone']==j['phone']:
             list3.append(j)

print(list3)
[{'phone': '123', 'name': 'Joey', 'accountid': 'ID_001'}, {'phone': '456', 'name': 'Erik', 'accountid': 'ID_006'}]
```

Comment: This is given that the list1 and list2 lengths are identical - what happens if list1 or list2 is not of similar length?

Answer (score 0):

```
var commonFound = []; 
for (var i = 0, len = listOne.length; i < len; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0, len2 = listTwo.length; j < len2; j++) { 
            if ((listOne[i].phone == listTwo[j].phone) && (listOne[i].name == listTwo[j].name)) {
                commonFound.push(listTwo[j])
            }
        }
    }
console.log(commonFound)
```

Comment: This is given that the listOne and listTwo lengths are identical - what happens if list one or list two is not of similar length?

Answer (score 0):

We have two properties to check such as `phone` and `name`. Based on this, we can filter an array:

```
const result = listTwo.filter(f=> 
    listOne.some(s => s.phone == f.phone && s.name == f.name));
```

This is an example:

```js
let listOne = [
    {phone: "123", name: "Joey"},
    {phone: "456", name: "Erik"},
    {phone: "789", name: "Teddy"},
];

let listTwo = [
    {phone: "123", name: "Joey", accoundId: "ID_001"},
    {phone: "456", name: "Erik", accoundId: "ID_006"},
    {phone: "5553", name: "Sebastian", accoundId: "ID_010"},
];

const result = listTwo.filter(f=> 
    listOne.some(s => s.phone == f.phone && s.name == f.name));

console.log(result);
```