# Remove duplicates from two separate arrays javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord.js

I am working on the `roleUpdate` event on my Discord bot, I have old role permissions, and new role permissions in the form of an array which prints:

```js
[ 'VIEW_AUDIT_LOG', 'MANAGE_ROLES' ] // Old Roles
[ 'MANAGE_GUILD', 'VIEW_AUDIT_LOG', 'MANAGE_ROLES' ] // New Roles
```

Following this example, the output I need would be `MANAGE_GUILD` as that is the only changed object.
How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare two Javascript Arrays and remove Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates)

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
newroles.filter((role) => !oldroles.includes(role));
```