# How to compare if two arrays have duplicate values and return the different value?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays and I would like to compare if these arrays have duplicated values, then return the values that aren't duplicates. Based on these two arrays I would like to return the string `Eucalipto`.

```js
const plants = [
  {
    id: 59,
    kind: "Cana-de-açucar"
  },
  {
    id: 60,
    kind: "Citros"
  }
];

const auxPlants = [
  "Cana-de-açucar",
  "Citros",
  "Eucalipto"
]
```

Comment: `auxPlants.filter(it => <it not in plants>)`

Comment: What did you try? What did you find when searching for a solution?

Comment: When I looked for the solution it only returns duplicate values, I want to bet it, return the different value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#map` to find all the `kind` values, pass that to the `Set` constructor, and then use `Array#filter` to find all elements of the array not in that `Set`.

```js
const plants = [
  {
    id: 59,
    kind: "Cana-de-açucar"
  },
  {
    id: 60,
    kind: "Citros"
  }
];
const auxPlants = [
  "Cana-de-açucar",
  "Citros",
  "Eucalipto"
];
const set = new Set(plants.map(({kind})=>kind));
const res = auxPlants.filter(x => !set.has(x));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @vbernal No problem.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want to filter the array of values you're interested in based on if they're not found in the other array, like so:

```
const nonDuplicates = auxPlants.filter(a => !plants.find(p => p.kind === a))
```

it's unclear if you'd also want values from the `plants` array that are non duplicate as well, or if you're only interested in uniques from the `auxPlants` array

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution to it, I have explained it's working using comments

```js
// create a set in order to store values in it
// assuming you have unique values
let set = new Set();
// iterating over array of object and storing the value of 'kind' in the set
for(obj of plants){
  set.add(obj.kind);
}

// iterating over array and checking for values in set, 
// if not in set then printing it
for(ele of auxPlants){
  if(!set.has(ele)){
    console.log(ele);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said, please search for an already posted solution first. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930516/compare-two-javascript-arrays-and-remove-duplicates) what I found.

Anyhow, the solution would be to separate the types of plants from the first array, as so:

```
const plantsTypes = plants.map(obj => obj.kind)
```

Then, filter out the non duplicates:

```
const nonDuplicates = auxPlants.filter(plant => !plantsTypes.includes(plant))
```

Note that it matters which array you call the .filter() function on.