# How to correctly use 'async, await and promises' in nodejs, while allocating values to a variable returned from a time-consuming function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, get

### Problem Statement:

- Our aim is to allocate values in the array `ytQueryAppJs`, which are returned from a time consuming function `httpsYtGetFunc()`.
- The values in `ytQueryAppJs` needs to be used many times in further part of the code, hence it needs to be done 'filled', before the code proceeds further.
- There are many other arrays like `ytQueryAppJs`, namely one of them is `ytCoverAppJs`, that needs to be allocated the value, the same way as `ytQueryAppJs`.
- The values in `ytCoverAppJs` further require the use of values from `ytQueryAppJs`. So a solution with clean code would be highly appreciated.

*(I am an absolute beginner. I have never used async, await or promises and I'm unaware of the correct way to use it. Please guide.)*

**Flow (to focus on):**

- The user submits a `queryValue` in index.html.
- An array `ytQueryAppJs` is logged in console, based on the query.

**Expected Log in Console (similar to):**

[image: Expected Log in Console]

**Current Log in Console:**

[image: Current Log in Console]

---

**Flow (originally required by the project):**

- User submits query in index.html.
- The values of arrays, `ytQueryAppJs`, `ytCoverAppJs`, `ytCoverUniqueAppJs`, `ytLiveAppJs`, `ytLiveUniqueAppJs` gets logged in the console, based on the query.

---

**Code to focus on, from 'app.js':**

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930567/14597561
function compareAndRemove(removeFromThis, compareToThis) {
  return (removeFromThis = removeFromThis.filter(val => !compareToThis.includes(val)));
}

// Declaring variables for the function 'httpsYtGetFunc'
let apiKey = "";
let urlOfYtGetFunc = "";
let resultOfYtGetFunc = "";
let extractedResultOfYtGetFunc = [];


// This function GETs data, parses it, pushes required values in an array.
async function httpsYtGetFunc(queryOfYtGetFunc) {

  apiKey = "AI...MI"
  urlOfYtGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&q=" + queryOfYtGetFunc + "&maxResults=4&order=relevance&type=video";

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // GETting data and storing it in chunks.
    https.get(urlOfYtGetFunc, (response) => {
      const chunks = []
      response.on('data', (d) => {
        chunks.push(d)
      })

      // Parsing the chunks
      response.on('end', () => {
        resultOfYtGetFunc = JSON.parse((Buffer.concat(chunks).toString()))
        // console.log(resultOfYtGetFunc)

        // Extracting useful data, and allocating it.
        for (i = 0; i < (resultOfYtGetFunc.items).length; i++) {
          extractedResultOfYtGetFunc[i] = resultOfYtGetFunc.items[i].id.videoId;
          // console.log(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
        }
        resolve(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
      })
    })
  })
  let result = await promise;
  return result;
}

app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  // Accessing the queryValue, user submitted in index.html. We're using body-parser package here.
  query = req.body.queryValue;

  // Fetching top results related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  ytQueryAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query);
  console.log("ytQueryAppJs:");
  console.log(ytQueryAppJs);
});
```

**Complete `app.post` method from app.js:**

(For better understanding of the problem.)

```js
app.post("/", function(req, res) {

  // Accessing the queryValue user submitted in index.html.
  query = req.body.queryValue;

  // Fetcing top results related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  ytQueryAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query);
  console.log("ytQueryAppJs:");
  console.log(ytQueryAppJs);

  // Fetching 'cover' songs related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  if (query.includes("cover") == true) {
    ytCoverAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query);
    console.log("ytCoverAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverAppJs);
  
    // Removing redundant values.
    ytCoverUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytCoverAppJs, ytQueryAppJs);
    console.log("ytCoverUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverUniqueAppJs);
  } else {
    ytCoverAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query + " cover");
    console.log("ytCoverAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverAppJs);
  
    // Removing redundant values.
    ytCoverUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytCoverAppJs, ytQueryAppJs);

    console.log("ytCoverUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverUniqueAppJs);
  }
  
  // Fetching 'live performances' related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  if (query.includes("live") == true) {
    ytLiveAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query);
    console.log("ytLiveAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveAppJs);
  
    // Removing redundant values.
    ytLiveUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytLiveAppJs, ytQueryAppJs.concat(ytCoverUniqueAppJs));

    console.log("ytLiveUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveUniqueAppJs);
  } else {
    ytLiveAppJs = httpsYtGetFunc(query + " live");
    console.log("ytLiveAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveAppJs);
  
    // Removing redundant values.
    ytLiveUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytLiveAppJs, ytQueryAppJs.concat(ytCoverUniqueAppJs));

    console.log("ytLiveUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveUniqueAppJs);
  }

  // Emptying all the arrays.
  ytQueryAppJs.length = 0;
  
  ytCoverAppJs.length = 0;
  ytCoverUniqueAppJs.length = 0;
  
  ytLiveAppJs.length = 0;
  ytLiveUniqueAppJs.length = 0;
});
```

Comment: have you tried to `await` `https.get`?

Comment: No, I have not tried it. Could you please guide how I can try it?

Comment: like this `let promise = await http....

Comment: @Areg Okay. Do I need to remove `let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {` and `let result = await promise;
  return result;` And where does `resolve(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);` go?

Comment: i was wrong actually, you cant use async/await on http module, consider using something like axios

Comment: @Areg Okay. I'm familiar with Axios. But I don't know how to implement async/await.

Comment: look at the answer for detailed usage

Answer (score 1):

I have just looked at the code I think the issue is how you are handling the async code in the request handler. You are not awaiting the result of the function call to `httpsYtGetFunc` in the body so when it returns before the promise is finished which is why you get the `Promise {Pending}`.

Another issue is that the array is not `extractedResultOfYtGetFunc` is not initialised and you may access indexes that don't exist. The method to add an item to the array is `push`.

To fix this you need to restructure your code slightly. A possible solution is something like this,

```js
// Declaring variables for the function 'httpsYtGetFunc'
let apiKey = "";
let urlOfYtGetFunc = "";
let resultOfYtGetFunc = "";
let extractedResultOfYtGetFunc = [];

// This function GETs data, parses it, pushes required values in an array.
function httpsYtGetFunc(queryOfYtGetFunc) {
  apiKey = "AI...MI";
  urlOfYtGetFunc =
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" +
    apiKey +
    "&part=snippet&q=" +
    queryOfYtGetFunc +
    "&maxResults=4&order=relevance&type=video";

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // GETting data and storing it in chunks.
    https.get(urlOfYtGetFunc, (response) => {
      const chunks = [];
      response.on("data", (d) => {
        chunks.push(d);
      });

      // Parsing the chunks
      response.on("end", () => {
        // Initialising the array
        extractedResultOfYtGetFunc = []
        resultOfYtGetFunc = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks).toString());
        // console.log(resultOfYtGetFunc)

        // Extracting useful data, and allocating it.
        for (i = 0; i < resultOfYtGetFunc.items.length; i++) {
          // Adding the element to the array
          extractedResultOfYtGetFunc.push(resultOfYtGetFunc.items[i].id.videoId);
          // console.log(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
        }
        resolve(extractedResultOfYtGetFunc);
      });
    });
  });
}

app.post("/", async function (req, res) {
  query = req.body.queryValue;

  // Fetching top results related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  ytQueryAppJs = await httpsYtGetFunc(query);
  console.log("ytQueryAppJs:");
  console.log(ytQueryAppJs);
});
```

Another option would be to use axios,
The code for this would just be,

```js
app.post("/", async function (req, res) {
  query = req.body.queryValue;

  // Fetching top results related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  try{
    ytQueryAppJs = await axios.get(url); // replace with your URL
    console.log("ytQueryAppJs:");
    console.log(ytQueryAppJs);
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

});
```

Using Axios would be a quicker way as you don't need to write promise wrappers around everything, which is required as the node HTTP(S) libraries don't support promises out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for replying, buddy. :) I went with the Axios way. First, I replaced all the `httpsYtGetFunc(query)` with `await axios.get(url);` inside of try. I had to pass different parameters for different searches, so I used the other syntax for Axios, at all places. The code was running just as expected. The code wasn't looking clean, so I created a function to contain this Axios code similar to `httpsYtGetFunc`. Now, all the arrays gets be logged in correct order, but `ytCoverUniqueAppJs` and `ytLiveUniqueAppJs` gets logged empty. I'm not able to figure the cause. Could you please help?

Comment: And you mentioned that `extractedResultOfYtGetFunc` is not initialised. Do I need to declare it anywhere inside the function as well?

Comment: I have asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67767513/14597561. Please visit for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can use the async/await on http module when making requests. You can install and use axios module . In your case it will be something like this

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Declaring variables for the function 'httpsYtGetFunc'
let apiKey = "";
let urlOfYtGetFunc = "";
let resultOfYtGetFunc = "";
let extractedResultOfYtGetFunc = [];


// This function GETs data, parses it, pushes required values in an array.
async function httpsYtGetFunc(queryOfYtGetFunc) {

  apiKey = "AI...MI"
  urlOfYtGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&q=" + queryOfYtGetFunc + "&maxResults=4&order=relevance&type=video";

  const promise = axios.get(urlOfYtGetFunc).then(data => {
   //do your data manipulations here
  })
  .catch(err => {
    //decide what happens on error
  })
```

Or async await

```
const data = await axios.get(urlOfYtGetFunc);

//Your data variable will become what the api has returned
```

If you still want to catch errors on async await you can use try catch

```
try{
  const data = await axios.get(urlOfYtGetFunc);
}catch(err){
  //In case of error do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response, pal. :) I went with the try-catch way. Now, all the arrays gets logged in the correct order. But `ytCoverUniqueAppJs` and `ytLiveUniqueAppJs` comes out empty. Could you please look into this as well?

Comment: I have asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67767513/14597561. Please visit for better clarity.

Comment: Hey Areg. You seemed to have made a type in the first sentence. "Unfortunately you can **_not_*** use the async/await..." Also, please look @Luke's answer. He's seemingly did it using https.get only. I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: @Varun he didnt directly use async await on that but rather created a wrapper promise, and i doubt if that will even work properly