# Empty array getting logged in, in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, async-await, axios

**Flow:**

- The user submits a `queryValue` in index.html.
- Three API calls are made (using a function called `ytAxiosGetFunc`) based on the `queryValue`.
- The returned values are put in three arrays: `ytQueryAppJs`, `ytCoverAppJs` and `ytLiveAppJs`.
- `ytCoverAppJs` and `ytLiveAppJs` contains redundant values. These are removed using a function called `compareAndRemove`.
- Two new arrays are allocated which contain unique values from for each of these respectively. These are `ytCoverUniqueAppJs` and `ytLiveUniqueAppJs`.
- Hence, a total of five arrays get logged in console, based on the query.

---

**Expected Console Log:**

All the arrays are filled.

[image: Expected Console Log]

**Current Console Log:**

All the arrays are filled, except `ytCoverUniqueAppJs` and `ytLiveUniqueAppJs`. These are empty.

[image: Current Console Log]

---

**Source Code from 'app.js':**

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/14930567/14597561
function compareAndRemove(removeFromThis, compareToThis) {
  return (removeFromThis = removeFromThis.filter(val => !compareToThis.includes(val)));
}

// Declaring variables for the function 'ytAxiosGetFunc'
let apiKey = "";
let urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc = "";

let ytResponse = "";
let ytExtractedResult = [];

// This function GETs data, parses it, allocates required values in an array.
async function ytAxiosGetFunc(queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc, maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc) {

  apiKey = "AI...5U"
  urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&order=relevance&type=video";

  try {
    ytResponse = await axios({
      url: urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc,
      method: "get",
      params: {
        q: queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc,
        maxResults: maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc
      }
    })

    let ytResult = ytResponse.data;

    for (i = 0; i < (ytResult.items).length; i++) {
      ytExtractedResult[i] = ytResult.items[i].id.videoId;
      // console.log(ytExtractedResult);
    }
    return (ytExtractedResult);

    ytExtractedResult.length = 0;
    ytResponse.length = 0;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

app.post("/", async function(req, res) {

  // Accessing the queryValue user submitted in index.html.
  query = req.body.queryValue;

  // Fetcing top results related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  ytQueryAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query, 4);
  console.log("ytQueryAppJs");
  console.log(ytQueryAppJs);


  // Fetching 'cover' songs related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  if (query.includes("cover") == true) {
    ytCoverAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query, 8);
    console.log("ytCoverAppJs");
    console.log(ytCoverAppJs);

    // Removing redundant values.
    ytCoverUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytCoverAppJs, ytQueryAppJs);

    console.log("ytCoverUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverUniqueAppJs);
  } else if (query.includes("live") == true) {
    ytCoverAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query.replace("live", " cover "), 8);
    console.log("ytCoverAppJs");
    console.log(ytCoverAppJs);

    // Removing redundant values.
    ytCoverUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytCoverAppJs, ytQueryAppJs);

    console.log("ytCoverUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverUniqueAppJs);
  } else {
    ytCoverAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query + " cover ", 8);
    console.log("ytCoverAppJs");
    console.log(ytCoverAppJs);

    // Removing redundant values.
    ytCoverUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytCoverAppJs, ytQueryAppJs);
    console.log("ytCoverUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytCoverUniqueAppJs);
  }

  // Fetching 'live performances' related to user's query and putting them in the array.
  if (query.includes("live") == true) {
    ytLiveAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query, 8);
    console.log("ytLiveAppJs");
    console.log(ytLiveAppJs);

    // Removing redundant values.
    ytLiveUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytLiveAppJs, ytQueryAppJs.concat(ytCoverUniqueAppJs));

    console.log("ytLiveUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveUniqueAppJs);
  } else if (query.includes("cover") == true) {
    ytLiveAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query.replace("cover", " live "), 8);
    console.log("ytLiveAppJs");
    console.log(ytLiveAppJs);

    // Removing redundant values.
    ytLiveUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytLiveAppJs, ytQueryAppJs.concat(ytCoverUniqueAppJs));

    console.log("ytLiveUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveUniqueAppJs);
  } else {
    ytLiveAppJs = await ytAxiosGetFunc(query + " live ", 8);
    console.log("ytLiveAppJs");
    console.log(ytLiveAppJs);

    // Removing redundant values.
    ytLiveUniqueAppJs = compareAndRemove(ytLiveAppJs, ytQueryAppJs.concat(ytCoverUniqueAppJs));

    console.log("ytLiveUniqueAppJs:");
    console.log(ytLiveUniqueAppJs);
  }

  // Emptying all the arrays.
  ytQueryAppJs.length = 0;

  ytCoverAppJs.length = 0;
  ytCoverUniqueAppJs.length = 0;

  ytLiveAppJs.length = 0;
  ytLiveUniqueAppJs.length = 0;
});
```

*(I am a beginner. Please guide and suggest a title to categorize this question for coming viewers.)*

Comment: Isn't it expected for `ytCoverUniqueAppJs` and `ytLiveUniqueAppJs` to be empty if there are no redundant values in `ytCoverAppJs`/`ytLiveAppJs` and `ytQueryAppJs`?

Comment: @painotpi Thank you for replying. I believe that `ytCoverUniqueAppJs` should still contain all the values of `ytCoverAppJs`. Since the `compareAndRemove` function returns `removeFromThis = removeFromThis.filter(val => !compareToThis.includes(val))`.

Comment: @painotpi Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: Is it like that when both `queryValue` is `live` and `cover`?

Comment: @Areg I didn't get you, But we figured it. I've put the answer in 'answers'.

Answer (score 0):

My friend suggested me to localise `ytResponse` and `ytExtractedResult`. So I declared them inside `ytAxiosGetFunc`.

Notice the commented code. Here's the required change:

```js
// Declaring variables for the function 'ytAxiosGetFunc'
let apiKey = "";
let urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc = "";

// let ytResponse = "";
// let ytExtractedResult = [];

// This function GETs data, parses it, allocates required values in an array.
async function ytAxiosGetFunc(queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc, maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc) {

  let ytExtractedResult = [];
  apiKey = "A...U"
  urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet&order=relevance&type=video";

  try {
    let ytResponse = await axios({
      url: urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc,
      method: "get",
      params: {
        q: queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc,
        maxResults: maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc
      }
    })

    let ytResult = ytResponse.data;

    for (i = 0; i < (ytResult.items).length; i++) {
      ytExtractedResult[i] = ytResult.items[i].id.videoId;
      // console.log(ytExtractedResult);
    }
    return (ytExtractedResult);

    // ytExtractedResult.length = 0;      // These are unnecessary now.
    // ytResponse.length = 0;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

**Here's what I think was happening earlier:**

- `ytQueryAppJs` was getting 're-filled' for every `ytAxiosGetFunc` call. This was making `ytQueryAppJs` to have exact same values (on the same index) as the variable for which the call is actually made. For example, if the function call is made to assign values in `ytCoverAppJs`, it would set the same values for `ytQueryAppJs` as well. The same would happen at the time of calling function for `ytLiveAppJs`. This ultimately caused `compareAndRemove` function to clear out all the values.

**Here's what I think is happening now:**

- The variables `ytExtractedResult` and `ytResponse` are being re-initialised for every call to the function `ytAxiosGetFunc`. This imply that they don't have the previous values. (And do not need to have their `length` set to zero.)

Thank you everyone for responding. :)

Comment: Your code looks correct, but you can simplify the Axios call a lot to make the code a bit neater. The request can be converted to:
`axios.get(urlOfYtAxiosGetFunc, {params: {q: queryOfYtAxiosGetFunc, maxResults: maxResultsOfYtAxiosGetFunc}})`
It is of course up to you but that just cleans the code up slightly.

Comment: Yes. It does make it cleaner. Thank you for suggesting, @LukeBraithwaite